# Massive memory consumption with cocos2d sprite sheets

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Per the [cocos2d best practices](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices#draw_vs_update), I've packed my key assets for my game into 4 separate sprite sheets. FWIW, I created these sheets with [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) and have crunched down the resultant .pngs with [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/). The largest sprite sheet of the 4 (which contains my dialogs) is `375KB` large and `2048x2048px` in the `-hd` variation (aka `@2x`).

I've been noticing memory issues in my game, so I booted up the `Allocations` tool in `Instruments`. Sure enough, the `Main scene` was using `~250MB` of memory on retina devices (`~95MB` on non-retina devices). Woah! Huge! Even worse, there is fairly significant lag on older retina devices (e.g., the iPhone 4).

The first thing I did was to remove one of the sprite sheets, to see if this was the problem. Sure enough, simply not loading a single sprite sheet dropped retina memory by `60MB`. Considering the sprite sheet in question is only `268KB` in filesize, I'm shocked that this is such a big problem.

Here's the code I'm using to "preload" a sprite sheet (during the app startup):

```
- (BOOL)cacheSpriteSheet:(NSString*)sheetName 
{
    if(!sheetName) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    NSString *fpSheet = [[AMAssetManager sharedManager] pathForSpriteSheet:sheetName];
    if(fpSheet) 
    {
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:fpSheet];
        return YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        Warn(@"NULL sheet for %@",sheetName);
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Question: **why are my sprite sheets consuming so much memory, and how can I fix it?**

Things I've tried so far:

1. `[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444]` helped to reduce memory footprint by ~20%, but I can only use it with some of the sprite sheets (others have, for example, radial gradients, which don't play nice).
2. `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames]` doesn't seem to help (memory footprint remains the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file size has nothing to do with anything when it comes to 'in core' size. A pixel is a pixel is a pixel and most likely, each and every one of those 2048x2048 pixels take 32 bits. Your options are to :

- split your sprite sheets, and load 'just in time' when you need the sprites.
- Dont trust instruments when running on the simulator. To be certain, use

  [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo]

to know how much memory is really consumed by your sprites.

- Memory allocations on simulator will give you very little useful indications. Build your release version, target a device, and monitor process size. That is more likely what will be the decisive factor before getting the dreaded memory warning.
- Dont use instruments/simulator to gain any appreciation of performance and user experience. They lie. Use the lowliest device you plan to support with your app as the litmus test
- Even if you remove unused sprite frames, if a single sprite frame (used) refers to a texture, it will still be retained.

Read this very interesting [article](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/) to grasp textures vs memory and the required trade-offs.

Comment: That article was excellent, thanks. The only reason I was using instrumentation was that the game was performing poorly on an iPhone4 (so, I was indeed using it on a device, not simulator). I just followed the recommendations in the article, repacking all my textures, and reduced memory usage by 90% (seriously, it went from ~200MB to ~15MB!)